# Fill blank cell in Excel with value with same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm not so advanced in excel I need help if is it possible to do.
I have an excel with this column:
ID - Value1 - Value2

I need to update the value1 (or value2):
- only if are blank  AND only if the row has the same ID

I make an example, I have this table:

```
    ID  Value1  Value2
A1  1   100 
A2  2       
A3  3       
A4  1            200
A5  2            250
```

Iwould like to fill all the empty cell in this way

```
    ID  Value1  Value2
A1  1   100      200
A2  2            250
A3  3       
A4  1   100      200
A5  2            250
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why dont you use a pivot table? Put `ID` in the Rows list and generate `Sum of Value1` and `Sum of Value2`.

Comment: Tank you for fast answer but... I put in my example only numbers, but the cell Value1 or Value2 could be a mixed number and text...

Comment: It is possible to generate the two new columns with formulas. Is that an option? To replace the blanks in place needs VBA.

Comment: If you can give me some step by step guide, yes is an option! ;-)

Comment: Okay, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your data is a mixture of numbers and texts. You can generate two new columns with the desired values using formulas. Choose two new, **adjacent** columns, say D and E, and enter this *CSE formula* in row say in cell `D2`:

```
D2:
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2),INDEX(B$2:B$99,
   MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$99=$A2)*(1-ISBLANK(B$2:B$99)),0)),B2), "")
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Enter the formula in `D2` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and then copy/paste in the cells of columns D and E (or as I said any two adjacent columns).

[image]