# Fill blank cell with value with same ID in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Dear stackoverflowers,

I looked through stackoverflow to solve my problem, and is exactly described with this post:
[Fill blank cell in Excel with value with same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824101/fill-blank-cell-in-excel-with-value-with-same-id)

In short, I have a column with an ID, and in my second column i got a description linked to the ID. I would like to copy this description to all the rows where this same ID appears in (when the description column is empty). In the post above, this excel composition was given:

```
D2:
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2),INDEX(B$2:B$99,
   MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$99=$A2)*(1-ISBLANK(B$2:B$99)),0)),B2), "")
```

This is exactly what I need, but the excel VBA code.Could anyone help me with converting this excel composition into an excel VBA code? Especially the Range argument for the MATCH function, as I keep getting an error on that.

I attempted something like this:

```
Dim desiredOutcome As String
If IsEmpty(Cells(2, 2).Value) = True Then
   desiredOutcome = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B2:B99"), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Range("A2:A99").Value = Cells(1, 2).Value) * (1 - IsEmpty(Range("B2:B99"))), 0)), "")
Else
   desiredOutcome = Cells(2, 2).Value
End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i edited my question. I assume something does not go right with my range definition in the MATCH function

Comment: In VBA you can't do `(Range("A2:A99").Value = Cells(1, 2).Value)` because the left-hand side is a 2D Variant array that you can't compare to the right-hand side. One option here is to use `Evaluate` and pass it your initial formula.

Comment: i tried with Evaluate, but does not seem to work either. Keep getting 'error 2015'. But thank you anyways.